# How to display the values of the arguments passed from another application in our current application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I am having a sample application which is having 2 text fields to contain integer values. I am having another application say "Sum" which is having 2 text fields to display 2 integer values. Now i am passing the arguments from sample application to sum application and i am getting the values of the arguments sent from sample application there.

The issue is when i try to display these values in the text fields of "sum" application, the values are not displayed, instead i get the previous state of the Sum application launched.

Clearly specifying i am able to display these values in alert view too, but the UI of sum application doesn't get updated. It shows the old existing screen.
Can any one help me on this?

Thank you all in advance,
James Lobo

Answer (score 1):

I just added the following code in my called applications app delegate class's "-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url" function and everything worked fine. Meaning the application refreshed itself.

```
    _viewController = [[sumViewController alloc] initWithArg1:arg1 andArg2:arg2];
    _viewController.delObj = self;
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```